# calabash-android run app-debug.apk throws exception

Tags: testing, calabash-android

I am trying to run calabash-android to test my app, but I get the following error, the same app without any modification was working before I tried to do some modifications, but then I reverted all the modifications to the app :

```
Exception occurred while dumping:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.bitbar.testdroid
    at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4134)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:18091)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackage(PackageManagerService.java:15508)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:888)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:792)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:118)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:94)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:18349)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:468)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:367)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2387)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3031)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

And then

```
Success
Success
  Scenario: I can choose a file from the Gallery # features/my_first.feature:3
  HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:8  (HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected)
  ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'
    When I take a screenshot                     # calabash-android-0.9.0/lib/calabash-android/steps/screenshot_steps.rb:9
    Then I take a screenshot                     # calabash-android-0.9.0/lib/calabash-android/steps/screenshot_steps.rb:9

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:3 # Scenario: I can choose a file from the Gallery

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (2 skipped)
0m6.240s
```

[Exception ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DshV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the build using the gradle task :app:assembleDebug
in the exception above, calabash can't find the package name, because it is on another dex class.
I think in calabash, they may be having problem with multidex projects, and Android Studio will always enable multidex to your app, even if it doesn't need it.
I am not an expert, any suggestion are welcome, and I hope some people can benefit from this answer.